# Flexdashboards and Leaflet and marker click with Highcharts

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, leaflet, flexdashboard

I am attempting to create a flexdashboard that uses an event (map_marker_click) in Leaflet to show a highcharts column chart in another chart on the same page.  I have taken from other examples and cannot find quite what I am looking for in the Flexdashboards tutorials or examples.  [This](https://github.com/walkerke/neighborhood_diversity/blob/master/neighborhood_diversity.Rmd) is very close to what I am wanting without the shiny inputs or plot.ly integration and using markers instead of polygons (much less going on).

I have the following code for a flexdashboard in R:

````
title: "Flexdashboards and Leaflet"
output: 
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r,include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(highcharter)
```

```{r,include=FALSE}
latitude<-c(35.94077, 35.83770, 35.84545, 35.81584, 35.79387, 36.05600)
longitude<-c(-78.58010, -78.78084, -78.72444, -78.62568, -78.64262,-78.67600)
amounts1<-c(27, 44, 34, 46, 25, 15)
amounts2<-c(34, 52, 35, 78, 14, 24)
ids<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
df<-data.frame(ids,amounts1,amounts2,latitude,longitude)
renderLeaflet({ 
leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>%
addMarkers(lng=c(longitude),lat=c(latitude))
}) 

observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
      click<-input$map_marker_click
      if(is.null(click))
        return()
}) 
```

```{r}
renderHighchart({
highchart() %>%
hc_chart(type = 'column')%>%
hc_add_series(name=amounts1, data=click())
hc_add_series(name=amounts2, data=click())
})
```
````

I am wondering if this could be accomplished in a flexdashboard with or without shiny integration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code will get it done.  In brief, the key steps are:

1. When initializing the map, be sure to specify a column as its `layerId`.  This way Leaflet will know which values to return when you specify an event.
2. Create an `eventReactive` that returns the value of that `layerId`.  You can then use this to subset your data as needed to pass to the chart.
3. I like to create a reactive data frame that is the subset of the master data frame based on the clicked `layerId`.  You could write the app without doing this but I like to separate my Shiny apps out into components as much as I can.
4. You can now use this reactive data frame - and its values - in your call to `renderHighchart`

Hope this helps!

````
---
title: "Flex Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(highcharter)

latitude<-c(35.94077, 35.83770, 35.84545, 35.81584, 35.79387, 36.05600)
longitude<-c(-78.58010, -78.78084, -78.72444, -78.62568, -78.64262,-78.67600)
amounts1<-c(27, 44, 34, 46, 25, 15)
amounts2<-c(34, 52, 35, 78, 14, 24)
ids<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
df<-data.frame(ids,amounts1,amounts2,latitude,longitude)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
output$map <- renderLeaflet({

  leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(data = df, lng = longitude, lat = latitude, 
               layerId = ~ids)

})

leafletOutput('map')  

```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

click_marker <- eventReactive(input$map_marker_click, {

  x <- input$map_marker_click

  return(x$id)

})

data_for_chart <- reactive({

  return(df[df$ids == click_marker(), ])

})

output$chart <- renderHighchart({

  highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(type = 'column') %>%
    hc_add_series(data = c(data_for_chart()$amounts1, 
                           data_for_chart()$amounts2))

})

highchartOutput('chart')

```
````